# Overriding an automatic property

Tags: c#

since this

```
public int MyInt{ get; set;}
```

is equivalent to

```
private int _myInt;
public int MyInt{ get{return _myInt;} set{_myInt = value;} }
```

when you make the automatic property virtual

```
public virtual int MyInt{ get; set;}
```

and then override this property in a child class

```
public override int MyInt{ get{return someVar;} set{someVar = value;} }
```

does this child class now have an unwelcomed and hidden allocation of _myInt?

Comment: Interesting question, and I don't know the answer, but isn't it possible to get the answer via reflection or a disassembler?

Comment: Not just the allocation, but the thing itself need not exist (since `get` ignores it, too).

Comment: @GrantThomas The backing field still needs to exist in base class, because you can access it this way: `((Base)childInstance).MyInt`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek If it's virtual/overriden, `((Base)childInstance).MyInt` will still resolve to `Child.MyInt`

Comment: Only you know that in your specific case `_myInt` is not required, however there are plenty of ways it can still be used: instance of the base class is created; `base.MyInt` is called; reflection is used. You are also in the same boat if the base property was a regular property. Although it's an interesting question, it wouldn't make any sense to have implemented this.

Comment: @SWeko True. But Marcin is right the field still has to exist, and it can be accessed non-virtually with `base.MyInt` from inside the derived class, like Adam said.

Comment: Of course, if you _never_ want to use the auto-field in the base class, and if the base class is (or can be made) `abstract` then you could make the property `abstract` as well, and in that case no implementation or backing field will be generated in the base class; but that is not what you ask, of course.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, the overriden property can be accessed from within the overriden class, but not from outside code. As the field is private, it can only be accessed indirectly, via the property (excluding reflection, of course).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

***Short Answer***: Yes, the `Child` allocates all `Base` class fields, so it still has the backing field allocated. However, you can't access it any other way than through `Base.MyInt` property.

***Long Answer***:

Quick disassembly results.

`Base` and `Child` classes implementation:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual int MyInt { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Base
{
    private int anotherInt;

    public override int MyInt
    {
        get { return anotherInt; }
        set { anotherInt = value; }
    }
}
```

[image]

**As you can see, the backing field exists within `Base` class.** However, it is private, so you can't access it from `Child` class:

```
.field private int32 '<MyInt>k__BackingField'
```

And your `Child.MyInt` property does not use that field. The property IL is:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname virtual 
    instance int32 get_MyInt () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2109
    // Code size 7 (0x7)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldfld int32 ConsoleApplication2.Child::anotherInt
    IL_0006: ret
} // end of method Child::get_MyInt

.method public hidebysig specialname virtual 
    instance void set_MyInt (
        int32 'value'
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2111
    // Code size 8 (0x8)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldarg.1
    IL_0002: stfld int32 ConsoleApplication2.Child::anotherInt
    IL_0007: ret
} // end of method Child::set_MyInt
```

Is uses `anotherInt` field, as you could expect.

The only ways to access the `'<MyInt>k__BackingField'` (indirectly, through `Base.MyInt` property) are:

- `base.MyInt` from within `Child` class

Comment: Is there a difference between Debug and Release builds?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead That's from Release. I don't think Debug differs here.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Are you implying that release mode could have optimised this away? I wouldn't have thought so as there are plenty of other angles that the backing field would still need to be used on.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I was just interested if - in this trivial example - there was a difference.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead It wouldn't be dropped by the compiler, but the JITter may never instantiate the unused field.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek How can I learn this much details about the framework?

Comment: @HaseebAsif Interesting question. First of all, I don't think I know the framework really good :) But the main way to know it better is just use it, and be curious about it: ask questions and try to answer them by yourself.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: 80K looks better than 79.9K ;-)

Answer (score 7):

It's not just equivalent its pretty much the actual implementation.  The compiler rewrites your automatic properties in its precompile stage. Albeit the field name will be named something else.

As a result the behaviour will be identical to you creating the property manually.

Yes the hidden field will exist, however it will not be assigned to because your override doesn't call the base implementation.

if you changed the override to

```
public override int MyInt
{
  get { return someVar; }
  set { 
    someVar = value;
    base.MyInt = value
  }
}
```

Then the allocation would occur

Comment: Are you saying fields don't allocate any memory if they're never assigned to?

Comment: @KyleDelaney No I'm saying it will always  have it's default value because the overridden method never told the base property the new value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just as if it was not defined as an automatic property.

The allocation is needed in the base class, because it still needs to exist and be useful. The base class has no knowledge of the existence of the derived class, and the derived class can use the backing field in its definition

If you have a base and derived class defined like:

```
public class Base
{
  public virtual string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Derived : Base
{
  private string _name;

  public override string Name 
  {
    get { 
      return _name; 
    }
    set 
    { 
      //access the base property we are overriding
      base.Name = value + " from derived";
      _name = value;
    }
  }
}
```

You can use reflection to see that the backing field of the base class does indeed exist, and behaves as expected:

```
Type tbase = typeof(Base);
FieldInfo fi = tbase.GetField("<Name>k__BackingField", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

Base b = new Base {Name = "Test"};

string baseValue = fi.GetValue(b).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(baseValue); //gives "Test";

Derived d = new Derived {Name = "Test" };

string derivedValue = fi.GetValue(d).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(derivedValue); //gives "Test from derived";
```

The name of the actual backing field is an undocumented implementation detail, so I wouldn't use it in any production code. (I got it by using LINQPad's IL View)

Comment: You mentioned above that the backing filed cannot be access via ((Base)childInstance).MyInt. Can you check/proof that via reflection, too, as far as most others state that this is possible.

Comment: @PVitt That's by definition of polymorphism. If I have an `List<Animal>` and I invoke a `Speak` method on all of them, the dog should bark, the cat should meow etc, without regard that they are referenced via a base class reference. Casting a child instance as base just changes the type of reference, it does nothing to the real type of the object.

Comment: Well, that's the theory. But as far as most others state that in practice the field CAN be accessed, I wanted to know what is true. I don't have a disassembler at hand, so I cannot check myself.

Comment: @PVitt - That's the practice too. The field is private, so excluding reflection, in cannot be directly accessed outside the class. The overriden property, on the other hand, cannot be accessed outside the overriding class, and within the overriding class can be accessed with the `base.PropertyName` syntax (which can in turn, *indirectly* access the private field).

Comment: Thanks. So the baseclass field can be accessed from the derived class using `base.PropertyName`. That's what I wasn't sure about.

Answer (score 2):

The MyInt field will be there and it needs to! The compiler cannot make optimization based on subclass information. Consider for example that the derived class may not may not be present in the packaged running program

*updated* as I had misread part of the question. Thanks @PVitt for pointing out.

Comment: The field should not be used by other methods on the base class as it's name is not defined. So your second reason is no reason at all.